# Can't compile SCSS

Tags: css, json, npm, cmd, sass

So I'm learning SCSS and I want to compile my SCSS into CSS using npm, so I type

`npm run compile: sass`

which in my package.json means

`"scripts": { "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css" },`

but this error message appears when I write the command

`Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\(user)\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\node-sass\bin\node-sass' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15) at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [] }`

Note: file names are correct in my Package.json file

Does anyone know what is going on?

If you need more information reply and I can provide you with the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its saying that you dont have the node-sass module installed have you tried npm install install node-sass in the project directory as per the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass .

Comment: I do have it installed and just retried to make sure but it still says the same error message

Comment: You can try to call from cli ./node_modules/.bin/node-sass.Did you install globally or locally?Have you checked the node_modules folder in your project directory for the node-sass folder?

Comment: I installed it locally I think on my laptop where I code by installing node js and then using it on my mini-project. I'm checking my folders and there is a node-sass folder but my computer keeps saying the same thing when I run compile:sass. And what do you mean to try to call it from cli? I'm new to this and the command line.

Comment: Which terminal app you are using?Try to run ./node_modules/.bin/node-sass from your project directory and see if you get output.

Comment: I'm using right now Powershell 7 and just now I tried this `./node_modules/.bin/node-sass  sass/main.scss css/style.css` and it worked!!! Thanks.
Although it doesn't work when I try to compile:sass don't know why?

Comment: No problem glad to help happy coding.Try to install globally with npm install -g node-sass maybe would fix it so you do need to use command.

Answer (score 0):

Your SASS folder have to be in same folder as node_modules folder, i had problem with bootstrap, i wrote script in package.json

"compile-dev": "sass --watch --update --style=expanded assets/scss:assets/css"

and script see assets/css folder but cannot goes back and see bootstrap.scss files in node_modules/bootstrap/scss/.

So the solution was to move node_modules in assets folder or to create scss folder in same directory as node_modules is in.

Then i rewrite script to :

"compile-dev": "sass --watch --update --style=expanded scss:assets/css"

and it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

And your script is wrong:
try:

```
"scripts":{
"compile:sass":"sass --watch sass/main.scss:css/style.css"
}
```

--watch - this is realtime compile command so while its runs every change is showed in realtime and compiled.
Dont use node-sass its just sass to call out program.

So basically use `sass` to call program `--watch` to tell program to compile after every change, `sass/main.scss` is your sass file that will be compiled to `css/style.css` file.